# Best way to check an attribute of an object that might be undefined

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object

I have an object (oUsed) containing "blocked" fields of a grid. If a field is blocked, it's "true". If it's not blocked, it's undefined.

What can happen now is, that a whole line (x coordinate value) is not blocked. So the following code will fail, as it checks the attribute of an undefined object.

```
    let oUsed = {
      "x1":{
        "y2": true; 
        "y3": true;
      }
      "x3":{
        "y2": true;
      }
    }
    let iY = 2;

    for (let iX=1;iX <= 3; iX++) {
        if (oUsed[`x${iX}`][`x${iY}`]) {
          break;
        }
    }
```

Doing it in two steps works, but it's not very pretty.

```
    for (let iX=1;iX <= 3; iX++) {
      if (oUsed[`x${iX}`]) {
        if (oUsed[`x${iX}`][`x${iY}`]) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

What's the best practice for this kind of check?

Comment: The best practice is not to use undefined! You can just create an array of items which are true, there is no need to separate them by true/undefined - bad practice. If you can't change the approach, you can use optional chaining operator: ```?.```

Comment: ```object['property']?.['anotherProperty']```

Comment: I would also just use a 2D array ( Nested array where each element is also an array ) filled with true/false or symbols. That way you can read the whole grid in code. You can directly use indexes without having to built a property name from the index. And most importantly, it gives us easy access to `.some()` and `.every()`, which are handy to check if a row or column is blocked. So save yourself some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Object.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) or [Object.hasOwn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)

```
 if (oUsed.hasOwnProperty(`x${iX}`) && oUsed[`x${iX}`][`x${iY}`])
```

or

use like this

```
 if (oUsed[`x${iX}`] && oUsed[`x${iX}`][`x${iY}`]) {
```

or if [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is supported by [your target browser](https://caniuse.com/?search=optional%20chaining)

```
if (oUsed[`x${iX}`]?.[`x${iY}`])
```

Comment: Why? if you can just use optional chaining?

Comment: Yes, I have added it, but all browsers dont support it.

Comment: note that [Object.hasOwn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) is recommended over `hasOwnProperty` for browsers that support it.